# Indexing issues with for loop

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong? I keep getting an index error. I have to model the 2d heat diffusion of a room. One wall is 50C, another is 40C and the other two are zero. And the room starts with air at 20C

```
N = 100
#temps#
Tair = 20
Twall1 = 50
Twall2 = 40
Twall34 = 0

T = np.empty([N,N])

#X-AXIS TEMP
for n in range(N):
  T[0][(n+1)] = Twall1  #row x column  50C
  T[0][n] = Twall1+Twall2
  T[n+1][0] = Twall2 # wall with 40C
  T[-1][n+1] = Twall34 #0C
  T[n+1][-1] = Twall34
  T[n+1:-1][n+1:-1] = Tair
```

Comment: What will `n+1` be at the end of the loop? I am pretty sure that is where you get index error as you will be looking for the 101 item in an array of 100 items.

Comment: So, to solve the problem alec_djinn mentions you might want to iterate until N-1 `for n in range(N-1)` Notice that then you might need to handle the special case of the last element separately. Also I'd recommend changing the name of the variable `n` for `i` so it could not be confused with `N` but also i is a more standard way of naming index iterators.